# IMPALA SQL (pivoting table)

Tags: sql, impala

Here I’ve got the IMPALA SQL task, can someone help me to solve it please

There is a table with three columns A B and C.
There are three types of values: child in column A; child/parent in column A and C; and owner in column B.

IF value appears in column C, then it is a parent value for other value in the same row  in the column A, and it also lives in column A a swell (as a child).

There are multiple levels of children and parents (child for one value can be parent for another).

All children and parent values are live together in column A;

Owners are live only in column B;

Children parent chain ends when owner appears (in column B).

I need to pivot existing table in a way that reveals every chain in a separate row

Child, parent-child 1, parent-child 2, parent-child 3, Owner.

[see pic_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl7kW.png)

I tried to solve this problem with LEFT JOINS

```
SELECT a.A, a.B, a.C,    b.A, b.B, b.C,   c.A, c.B, c.C
FROM  
table1 a 
LEFT JOIN
table1 b
ON a.C = b.A
LEFT JOIN
table1 c 
ON b.C = c.A
```

it works but it is a bad solution because we don’t know how many levels of ‘parent-child’ can be there. some chains are consist of only three parent/child
values and some of them have 50 'chain-rings' prior to the owner

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data, expected outcome, and what you have tried so far